# highlight the difference between two tables and store the differences in another table

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a c# application. I also have two orders tables, tblOrderLive and tblOrderTemp in my SQL database (version 2012). Both tables have a primary key called OrderId.

Each day the contents of tblOrderTemp are deleted and orders from the last 3 months are loaded in via a text file. Any orders that are in tblOrderTemp but not in tblOrderLive will be added to tblOrderLive.

It is also possible that an order has changed (not the OrderId but maybe the Payment type, expected delivery date or the order value etc.

Brief example of the tables

**tblOrdersLive**

```
OrderId  PaymentType   DateDelivery   OrderValue
1223     Cash          2018-05-01     1000
1255     Credit        2018-05-05     1325
1189     Cash          2018-05-05     800
1093     Cash          2018-05-04     55
```

**tblOrdersTemp**

```
OrderId  PaymentType   DateDelivery   OrderValue
1223     Cash          2018-05-01     900          -- order value changed
1255     Credit        2018-05-05     1325
1189     Credit        2018-07-05     800          -- payment type & date changed
1093     Cash          2018-05-04     55
```

What I want to be able to do is the following.

Where there are orders in both tables with the same OrderId but one of the fields has changed (so in my example above the 1st row the order value changed & in the 3rd row the payment type and delivery date changed) for these changes to be logged into a third table which would look like below,

**tblOrderLog**

```
OrderId DateLog     OldValue    NewValue    FieldName
1223    2018-04-11  1000        900         OrderValue
1189    2018-04-11  Cash        Credit      PaymentType
1189    2018-04-11  2018-05-05  2018-07-05  DateDelivery
```

So I am wondering the best way to do this, also in the real example there are about 20 fields we need to check? Can it all be done (/should it be done) in SQL? Currently I am thinking of doing this in my C# application.

My current plan in C# (not sure this is the best way hence my question) is to have an Orders object. Download two lists (Live & Temp) of type Orders. Then in my orders class implement the *IEqualityComparer interface* two highlight where two orders with the same OrderId have different values. Then I would have to loop through all the fields to find which are different and upload these to the SQL table tblOrderLog.

Comment: Create trigger in SQL.

Comment: @SeM I know a little about triggers but how would this work?

Comment: Well, you can create trigger on update (or insert in ordersLive), then get previous and current values, do your checking, then log it into a third table. Here is [article in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql).

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant database tag (product tag and version tag). Also, sample data is best served as as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). (I would probably recommend an SQL solution for this)

Comment: Of course the same thing you can achieve from `c#` code too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server, compare 2 tables with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261241/sql-server-compare-2-tables-with-dynamic-columns)